# Python Tkinter. Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку добавлялась определенная надпись в LabelFrame?

Tags: python, tkinter, button, label

Есть программа светофор, весь код ниже. Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на одну из кнопок, которые создаются в цикле добавлялась надпись в окно "Логовиця" скриншот программы внизу.
**Создание кнопок в ЦИКЛЕ:**

```
curRad = []
for col in range(3):
    curRad.append(tk.Radiobutton(traffic, text=colors[col], variable=radVar,
                                 value=col, command=radCall))
    curRad[col].grid(column=col, row=1, sticky=tk.W)  # row=6
```

**Изменение цвета светофора при нажатии на кнопку:**

```
def radCall():
        radSel = radVar.get()
        if radSel == 0:
            traffic_lighter("Red")
        elif radSel == 1:
            traffic_lighter("Yellow")
        elif radSel == 2:
            traffic_lighter("Green")
```

**СОЗДАНИЕ LabelFrame:**

```
logger = ttk.Labelframe(tab1, text="Логовиця")
logger.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=8, pady=4)
```

**ВЕСЬ КОД ПРОГРАММЫ:**

```
def laba2():
    for id in tabControl.tabs():
        tabControl.forget(id)

    tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)  # Create a tab
    tabControl.add(tab1, text='Завдання 2')  # Add the tab

    tabControl.pack(expand=1, fill="both")  # Pack to make visible

    traffic = ttk.LabelFrame(tab1, text=' Світлофор ')
    traffic.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=8, pady=4)

    def _logger(msg="Hello"):
        pass

    def _popmenu(event, param):
        pass
    # СОЗДАНИЕ ЛОГО
    logger = ttk.Labelframe(tab1, text="Логовиця")
    logger.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=8, pady=4)
    # Using a scrolled Text control
    scrol_w = 30
    scrol_h = 14
    scrol = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(logger, width=scrol_w, height=scrol_h, wrap=tk.WORD)
    scrol.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="NESW", columnspan=3)

    remove_control = ttk.LabelFrame(tab1, text=' Пульт ')
    remove_control.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=8, pady=4)

    logger_control = ttk.LabelFrame(tab1, text=' Логовиця ')
    logger_control.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=8, pady=4)

    def _cleaner_scrol():
        pass

    cleaner = ttk.Button(logger_control, text="Очистити", command=_cleaner_scrol)
    cleaner.pack(padx=10, pady=20)
    # First, we change our Radiobutton global variables into a list
    colors = ["Red", "Yellow", "Green"]

    def traffic_lighter(color=None):
        for clr in range(3):
            canvas = tk.Canvas(traffic, width=80, height=80, highlightthickness=1)
            fill_color = colors[clr] if color == colors[clr] else None
            traffic_lighter_color = colors[clr]
            oval = canvas.create_oval(1, 1, 79, 79, fill=fill_color, outline="Black", tag="ovals")
            canvas.grid(row=clr, column=4)
            canvas.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event, param={"color": traffic_lighter_color,
                                                           "cur_color": fill_color,
                                                           }: _popmenu(event, param))

    traffic_lighter()

    # We have also changed the callback function to be zero-based, using the list
    # instead of module-level global variables
    # Radiobutton Callback


    # ИЗМЕНЕНИЕ ЦВЕТОВ ПРИ НАЖАТИИ НА КНОПКУ
    def radCall():
        radSel = radVar.get()
        if radSel == 0:
            traffic_lighter("Red")
        elif radSel == 1:
            traffic_lighter("Yellow")
        elif radSel == 2:
            traffic_lighter("Green")

    # create three Radiobuttons using one variable
    radVar = tk.IntVar()

    # Next we are selecting a non-existing index value for radVar
    radVar.set(99)

    # ТУТ СОЗДАЮТСЯ 3 РАДИОКНОПКИ
    curRad = []
    for col in range(3):
        curRad.append(tk.Radiobutton(traffic, text=colors[col], variable=radVar,
                                     value=col, command=radCall))
        curRad[col].grid(column=col, row=1, sticky=tk.W)  # row=6

    # СОЗДАНИЕ ПУЛЬТА
    chVar = tk.IntVar()
    check1 = tk.Checkbutton(remove_control, text="Вкл.", variable=chVar)
    check1.select()
    check1.pack(padx=10, pady=20)

    # ПРИ НАЖАТИИ НА ВКЛ, КНОПКИ ВКЛЮЧАЮТСЯ\ОТКЛЮЧАЮТСЯ (ПУЛЬТ)
    def checkCallback(*ignoredArgs):
        if chVar.get():
            for i in range(3):
                curRad[i]['state'] = 'normal'

            pass
        else:
            for i in range(3):
                curRad[i]['state'] = 'disabled'
                traffic_lighter("None")
        pass

    chVar.trace('w', lambda unused0, unused1, unused2: checkCallback())
```

**Скриншот окна программы:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если нужно чтобы добавлялся текст в текстовое поле (ScrolledText), то в него и добавляйте (`scrol.insert(END, "text\n")`). Или я не так понял вопрос?

Comment: Да, нужно чтобы текст в ScrolledText добавлялся. А можно поподробнее на счет (scrol.insert(END, "text\n")), что такое END?
Я написал так:
    scrol = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(logger, width=scrol_w, height=scrol_h, wrap=tk.WORD)
    scrol.insert(END, "Text")
Но выдаёт ошибку: NameError: name 'END' is not defined

Comment: END нужно импортировать из модуля tkinter.

Comment: Всё работает, спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно добавлять текст не в `LabeledFrame`, а в текстовое поле `ScrolledText`. Это делается аналогично вставке в обычное текстовое поле `Text`:

```
import tkinter as tk

...

# tk.END означает, что текст будет добавляться в конце,
# после всего текста, что уже есть в текстовом поле
scrol.insert(tk.END, "text\n")
```